# AddfieldtoFilter by a list of emails

Tags: magento-1.8, filter

I'm trying to get a collection of orders by 2 clients using their emails. I tried this :

```
$CollectionOforders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',array('in' => array('client1@email.com','client2@email.com'))->addFieldToFilter('status','complete');
```

But i got this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `)` in your code:

```
->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',array('in' => array('client1@email.com','client2@email.com'))
```

Should be:

```
->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',array('in' => array('client1@email.com','client2@email.com')))
```

(see the extra `)` at the end)